# Solution organization with a primary configuration/index project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

1. I have a series of .NET MVC 5 projects I'll be creating that will be used by different departments in my organization with a central index. I'd like to set up a project that contains the css, scripts, images, layouts, error pages, and eventually forms authentication logic/pages. I would then want sub-projects that inherit all of those things so that I don't have to duplicate them for each.
2. As far as the url structure goes, I'd want to get to the index like this:

   ```
   www.companyname.com/AppCentral
   ```

   And to get to one of the sub-projects (TimeKeeping):

   ```
   www.companyname.com/AppCentral/TimeKeeping/Home
   ```

I currently have one project with all of the Controllers/Views/etc for each sub-project lumped in with one another, which can be cluttered. How can I structure my solution so that one project governs css, scripts, images, layouts, error pages, and authentication for sub-projects, so that I may have better separation between projects without having to repeat code/config?

Those structures may have separate solutions, so I numbered them for easier reference. My apologies if this question has been asked a lot, or is often found in references. I was unsure how to find a concept like this using a search engine.

Comment: You say "My apologies if this question has been asked a lot" but you never actually asked a question. Make your question explicitly clear! As it is, I have no idea how much you've done or what you're stuck at.

Comment: You're right. I made an edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I still don't understand your current situation is. Do you have one `.sln` file and you have multiple projects (`.csproj`) in it? Or do you just want one `.sln` and one `.csproj`?

Comment: I was (incorrectly) making the assumption that multiple projects would be required, since I was unaware of the existence of "areas". Thanks for the help clarifying my question, mason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you searching for [areas](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html) that appeared in **MVC 5**.

If you use them you still have all your base logic and styles in the same project but can customize `Views`, `Controller` logic and `ViewModels`.

Comment: That presumes that all the code is in a single project. Which it doesn't appear to be based on the question. I could be wrong though, it was a little fuzzy.

Comment: Though I was initially thinking it would involve creating separate projects, this may work well for me. I will look into this and give an update. Thank you for the comment.